# Drawing triangles with CSS problems

Tags: css

This code

```
.right {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 200px;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  position: relative;
  top:-800px;
  left:600px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

creates a triangle that looks like this in Safari:

[image]

But in other browsers there are problems. On firefox on mac the triangle has lines through it like this:

[image]

How can I make sure the lines do not appear? I would prefer not to replace the css triangle with an image.

Comment: Can you give a direct link so that we can see the issue?

Comment: www.brisbanefineartauctions.com.au

Comment: Looks fine in Windows Firefox 6. You sure you aren't zoomed in or something? Pressing Ctrl + 0 should reset the zoom level. Also there is no need to use transform, you just need to change around the borders.

Comment: Some people have reported seeing this. I used adobe browserlab and this appeared so I assume it is a problem on some browsers, but not others.

Comment: I see this on firefox 6.0.1 on osx lion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the zoom is not the problem, I think the problem is being caused by rotating the elements. It is unnecessary and can be done simply with the borders. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/TQx7x/

Remove the transforms and adjust border styles as below:

```
.left {
    border-color: transparent #ffffff transparent transparent; /* change to this */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 200px;
    height: 0;
    left: -400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -400px;
    width: 0;
}
.right {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff; /* change to this */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 200px;
    height: 0;
    left: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -800px;
    width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I read all of the comments and I found the solution. Please follow [link](http://www.knowahead.in/2012/10/css-triangles-make-triangles-in-html-without-images/).

Answer (score 0):

You have the default font size of your browser increased. ctrl+0 or cmd+0 (PC / Mac) should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using border-color #ffffff ?

```
  border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
```